# How to change user to root in an SFTP client?

Tags: security, user-management, sftp

It is always suggested on first step to disable the remote `root` login for the SSH protocol.
I have a low-right user able to connect via SSH and once connected, I simply `su` in order to gain more rights.

Now when using an SFTP client, I use my low-right user and am thus able to do next to nothing.

My question is : Is it possible to change user after login using 3rd party client, such as Transmit, Cyberduck, FileZilla? (Mac clients would be great)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to elevate your privileges within sftp.

Ideally you should fix the filesystem permission so that don't need root privileges to download/upload whatever you are working on.

If changing permissions isn't an option, then there is a compromise between disabling root logins, and logins with a password.  You could set `PermitRootLogin without-password` and then simply use key-based authentication.

Comment: Interesting solution to use keys + password. Hadn't tought of that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely true that you cannot change the user with SFTP.

For example, even if you are connecting to the common OpenSSH server, you can instruct it to run the SFTP subsystem/server with elevated privileges using a SFTP server startup command like:

```
sudo /path/to/sftp-server
```

For example with OpenSSH `sftp` client you can use something like:

```
sftp -s "sudo /path/to/sftp-server" user@example.com
```

Or with (my) WinSCP SFTP client you can also override the SFTP server start command (both in [GUI](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_sftp) and scripting).

But there's lot of limitations to allow this working. Particularly the `sudo` may not require password and TTY. For details, see WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)